# How to inspect Android app created using MAUI?

Tags: android, mobile, maui, mobile-development

I have created a standard maui application with a counter on the main page. and here's the question, how can I inspect the elements as in a web application. to see which styles are accepted in any element of the page.

I was trying to find out if there is such functionality in the official documentation, and maybe someone asked a similar question. I didn't find anything suitable, only for web applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like `Inspect Element` the closest thing you have is called Live Visual Tree, if you don't have a MAC just search for Visual tree in Global search.

[image]

Comment: This also exists in Visual Studio on Windows

Comment: Yeah i think its called Visual tree, That's why I said global search for it, not sure if its under View or not though

Comment: If this solves your issue don't forget to mark it as correct